Error alert not working in button function connection with input in react
I have a log in button and when clicked it has an alert that says log in was successful, but I'm trying to add an error alert if input is empty that will says Please enter your information and it's not working. Can anyone help me please to figure it out.
Thank you.
Below is the code I have:
function ModalLogIn ({open, onClose }) {

    const [valueName, setValueName] = useState('');
    const [valueLast, setValueLast] = useState('');

    const clickToLogIn = () => {
        if(!valueName && !valueLast) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                text: "Please enter your information!"
            }); 
        }
        else{
            Swal.fire("Your login was successful!");
        }
   
        setValueName('')
        setValueLast('')
        onClose(null)
    }

    const handleChange =(e) => {
         setValueName (e.target.valueName)
         setValueLast(e.target.valueLast)
       
    if(!open) return null
    return (
        <div onClick={onClose} className="overlay">
            <div onClick={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }}
              className="modalContainer"
            >
                <div className="modalRight">
                    <img className='icon' src={logIn} alt='icon'/>
                    <button className="closeBtn" onClick={onClose}>X</button>
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                    
                    <p>Log in</p>
                    <input 
                        className="inputModal"
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="User name..."
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={valueName}
                    />
                    <input className="inputModal" 
                        type="email" 
                        placeholder="Password..."
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={valueLast}
                    />
                    <button className='btnLog' onClick={clickToLogIn}>Log in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    )
}
export default ModalLogIn;


Thank you for the explanation but it's still not working how it supposed to. Now only the error alert it's showing even if the information is entered.

Never mind it work, the problem was that on the handleChange function I added setValueName(e.target.valueName) instead of (e.target.value) fixing that it did fixed my problem

Here is the explation for your error.
The handleChange function is incorrectly attempting to set both valueName and valueLast from the same event. Each input should have its own onChange handler.
The handleChange function does not have a way to differentiate between the two inputs.
The onClose function is being called with null after every login attempt, which may not be the intended behavior.
You are resetting the input values and closing the modal even when there is an error.
here is the fixed version
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

function ModalLogIn({ open, onClose }) {
    const [valueName, setValueName] = useState('');
    const [valueLast, setValueLast] = useState('');

    const clickToLogIn = () => {
        if (!valueName || !valueLast) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                text: "Please enter your information!"
            });
        } else {
            Swal.fire("Your login was successful!");
            setValueName('');
            setValueLast('');
            onClose(null);
        }
    };

    const handleNameChange = (e) => {
        setValueName(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleLastChange = (e) => {
        setValueLast(e.target.value);
    };

    if (!open) return null;

    return (
        <div onClick={onClose} className="overlay">
            <div
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }}
                className="modalContainer"
            >
                <div className="modalRight">
                    <img className='icon' src={logIn} alt='icon' />
                    <button className="closeBtn" onClick={onClose}>X</button>
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                    <p>Log in</p>
                    <input
                        className="inputModal"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="User name..."
                        onChange={handleNameChange}
                        value={valueName}
                    />
                    <input
                        className="inputModal"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password..."
                        onChange={handleLastChange}
                        value={valueLast}
                    />
                    <button className='btnLog' onClick={clickToLogIn}>Log in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ModalLogIn;

